# Laravel Soft Delete posts

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

**in our project we must be use soft delete for each posts. in laravel document i think we can only use this feature for tables.**

*can we use that for posts on table such as*

```
$id = Contents::find($id);
$id->softDeletes();
```

Answer (score 134, accepted):

### Updated Version ([Version 5.0 & Later](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#soft-deleting)):

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Post extends Model {

    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'posts';

    // ...
}
```

> When soft deleting a model, it is not actually removed from your
> database. Instead, a `deleted_at` timestamp is set on the record. To
> enable soft deletes for a model, specify the `softDelete` property on
> the model ([Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#soft-deleting)).

### For ([Version 4.2](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#soft-deleting)):

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait; // <-- This is required

class Post extends Eloquent {

    use SoftDeletingTrait;

    protected $table = 'posts';

    // ...
}
```

### Prior to Version 4.2 (But not 4.2 & Later)

For example (Using a `posts` table and `Post` model):

```
class Post extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'posts';
    protected $softDelete = true;
    
    // ...
}
```

> To add a **deleted_at** column to your table, you may use the `softDeletes`
> method from a migration:

For example (Migration class' `up` method for `posts` table) :

```
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        // more fields
        $table->softDeletes(); // <-- This will add a deleted_at field
        $table->timeStamps();
    });
}
```

Now, when you call the `delete` method on the model, the `deleted_at` column will be set to the current `timestamp`. When querying a model that uses soft deletes, the "deleted" models will not be included in query results. To `soft delete` a model you may use:

```
$model = Contents::find( $id );
$model->delete();
```

Deleted (soft) models are identified by the `timestamp` and if `deleted_at` field is `NULL` then it's not deleted and using the `restore` method actually makes the `deleted_at` field `NULL`. To permanently delete a model you may use `forceDelete` method.

Comment: The documentation has updated, the new answer by @majidarif should be accepted as correct

Comment: I've updated @AakilFernandes and it was given for prior to `version 4.2` and which was right so I think I don't deserve a down vote for this answer but anyways :-)

Comment: Perhaps would be nice to reorder the answer's sections sorted by latest updates first? Seems a little archaic to have to scroll a ways through historical non-applicables. Thanks for the answer though, was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Awesome! https://www.scratchcode.io/how-to-use-the-laravel-soft-delete/

Answer (score 26):

You actually do the normal delete. But on the model you specify that its a softdelete model.

So on your model add the code:

```
class Contents extends Eloquent {

    use SoftDeletingTrait;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

}
```

Then on your code do the normal delete like:

```
$id = Contents::find( $id );
$id ->delete();
```

Also make sure you have the `deleted_at` column on your table.

Or just see the docs: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#soft-deleting

Comment: then if how to delete normal posts in this model?

Comment: you can use `$user->forceDelete();`

Comment: my means is how to do not use SoftDelete? `delete` in normal mode delete from database. i think `forceDelete()` delete from `Trash` yes?

Comment: Laravel 4.2 uses Trait to soft delete records. The accepted answer is not working with Laravel 4.2.

Comment: Make sure to `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait;`

Answer (score 17):

I just did this with Laravel 8 and it worked. It's basically what @The alpha said, but trying to wrap everything quicker. Follow this steps.

In the **migration** file add:

```
$table->softDeletes();
```

In the **model**:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class User extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    ...
];
```

}

In the **controller**:

```
$user->delete();
```

**Bonus**: if you need to restore the deleted user

```
User::withTrashed()->find($id);->restore();
```

Answer (score 6):

Just an update for Laravel 5:

In Laravel 4.2:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait;    
class Post extends Eloquent {

    use SoftDeletingTrait;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

}
```

becomes in Laravel 5:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class User extends Model {

    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
```

Answer (score 4):

In Laravel 5.5 Soft Deleted works ( for me ).

**Data Base**

***deleted_at*** Field, default **NULL** value

**Model**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class User extends Model {
    use SoftDeletes;
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    User::find($id)->delete();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the Latest version of Laravel i.e **above Laravel 5.0**. It is quite simple to perform this task.
In Model, inside the class just write 'use SoftDeletes'. Example

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class User extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
}
```

And In Controller, you can do deletion. Example

```
User::where('email', 'youremail@example.com')->delete();
```

or

```
User::where('email', 'youremail@example.com')->softDeletes();
```

Make sure that you must have 'deleted_at' column in the users Table.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the details from laravel.com

http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#soft-deleting

When soft deleting a model, it is not actually removed from your database. Instead, a deleted_at timestamp is set on the record. To enable soft deletes for a model, specify the `softDelete` property on the model:

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    protected $softDelete = true;

}
```

To add a deleted_at column to your table, you may use the `softDeletes` method from a migration:

```
$table->softDeletes();
```

Now, when you call the delete method on the model, the deleted_at column will be set to the current timestamp. When querying a model that uses soft deletes, the "deleted" models will not be included in query results.

Answer (score 0):

### Updated Version (5.0 & later)

> To enable this feature, we need to add a `deleted_at` column in our
> database (or migration) for mapping purposes.

**For example:**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        ...
        $table->softDeletes(); // soft delete
    });
}
```

> In addition, we need to use `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes`
> trait on the model

**For example:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class User extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

}
```

> We can now call the `delete()` method as before

```
$user->delete();
```

For official documentation [click here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/folio#soft-deleted-models).