# Deleting the user

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to soft delete the user.

This is what i added in user model.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract
{
   use SoftDeletes;
   protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
```

and deleted_at column in users table:

And in the controller:

```
public function delete()
{
    User::where(['id'=>1])->softdeletes();
}
```

On calling this function, it gives

> Call to undefined method softdeletes()

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22426165/laravel-soft-delete-posts

Comment: So, just do ->delete(); instead of ->softdeletes();

Comment: @Liam got it with the link.