# Laravel: Soft Delete an item

Tags: php, laravel, soft-delete

I would like to delete an item only on my page "overview" however I will wish to keep the element on my database.  Is it possible ?

Do you have an idea of the procedure ?

I don't know how to do softdelete, in my Controller I have that

```
public function destroy(Devis $devis)
     {
         $devis->delete();
         return redirect('/admin');
     }
```

In my route I have that

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@getHome');
    Route::get('/valider/{devis}', 'AdminController@destroy');
});
```

In my file overview I have that

```
@foreach($devis as $item)
                <tr>
                   <td> {{$item->firstname}}</td>
                   <td> {{$item->lastname}} </td>
                   <td> {{$item->phone}} </td>
                   <td> {{$item->start_adress}} --  {{$item->start_floor}}</td>
                   <td> {{$item->end_adress}} --  {{$item->end_floor}}</td>
                   <td> {{$item->type_intervention}}</td>
                   <td> {{$item->email}} </td>
                   <td> {{$item->remarks}} </td>
                   <td> <a href="/valider/{{$item->id}}" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="left ion-close"></span></a></td>
                </tr>
              @endforeach
```

Comment: here is some great explaintion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22426165/laravel-soft-delete-posts

Comment: Try to use google before asking on SO unless you don't understand how it works and need a different explanation. Don't just ask your questions without searching on google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel already did it look [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#soft-deleting) so you add deleted_at in your model and 
 as docs said your model is like:

```html
  namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Flight extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    /**
     * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Using **Soft Deletion** you mark an item in a way that it's no longer displayed 
>   within the application.
>   Laravel natively support soft deletion, you just have to enable it on the 
>   specific model where you need it.

In **Laravel 5 or later**,  if you have for example the model **Book**, in order to enable it you need to:

**1. Create a new migration**

```sh
 $ php artisan make:migration add_soft_delete_to_books --table=books
```

**2. Modify the migration adding the "deleted_at" column**. The Laravel schema builder contains a helper method **softDeletes()** to create this column.

```
public function up()
{
     Schema::table('books', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
 }

public function down()
{
    Schema::table('books', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->dropColumn('deleted_at');
    });
}
```

**3) Run the migration**

```sh
$ php artisan migrate
```

**4) Open the Book model and add the SoftDelete trait**

```
<?php 
    namespace App;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
     use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

 class Book extends Model {  
    use SoftDeletes;  
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];  
}
```

**5) The next time you delete a record associated with this model, the deleted_at column will be set to the current timestamp.**

Any record having a set deleted_at timestamp will not be included in any retrieved results.
6) If you need to include the soft deleted record in any eloquent query result, you can use the withTrashed method:

```
$Books = Book::withTrashed()->get();
```

You see find here the official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#soft-deleting):

Answer (score 0):

When you want to soft delete actually you need a flag. Let's say that in your table you have a column *deleted* which accepts boolean values.

When you retrieve the data in your controller to pass it to the view then you will query the table you just put a `where` clause to your query something like:

```
->where('deleted',0)
```

So you get the "undeleted" items.

Now when you want to softdelete actually you don't delete but you update your column to set it's status to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Use this: [Documentation soft deleting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#soft-deleting)
later add to the conditions for downloading items

```
->whereNull('deleted_at')
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add a field to `soft delete` when creating the table. It's best to migrate. If it will be and you'll use `soft delete` then:

```
$ item-> delete () - will be softdelete

$ item-> forcedelete () - will permanently delete
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has it's own implementation of soft deleting. Simply add `use SoftDeletes` to your model, and it starts working. Try reading [Eloquent - Soft deletes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#soft-deleting) to learn more about it and its implications on your code.

Answer (score 0):

**1) For add column to default user table:**

```
`php artisan make:migration add_column_delete_soft --table="user"`(if already migrate)
```

-add above migration inside

`$table->SoftDeletes();`

> -if not migrate then follow this step:

```
    1) add `$table->SoftDeletes()`; in create_user migration then follow below process as same.
```

**2) Put in Model/User.php**

> -put below package:

```
 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
```

-add below line:

```
use SoftDeletes;
```

-Add below line after $fillable:

```
protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
```

**3) Add Controller inside delete method as you want to delete.**

```
public  function delete(Request $request)
{
      User::where('email', $request->email)->delete();
}
```

**4) if you want to return Null then follow below steps:**

**Route inside:**
// soft delete data again null

```
Route::get('restore/{id}', [AuthController::class, 'restoredata']);
```

**Controller inside:**

```
  public function restoredata(Request $request, $id)
    {
        User::onlyTrashed()->find($id)->restore();
        return 'deleted null Successfully';
    }
```

**For delete all data from database(not soft delete)**

> -do in controller

```
$delete_data = User::where('email', $request->email)->forceDelete();
```