# how to get auth information in AppService provider?

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I'm trying to give a condition is user suspend, user should redirect to login page if user in login state.

I have tried to give a check in AppServiceProvider like below

```
public function boot()
{
    if(auth()->user()->is_deleted === true) return redirect('/logout');
}
```

Problem is in AppServiceProvider I'm not getting any auth information. How I can solve this problem ?

Comment: This is because AppService provider is being loaded before AuthService provider, you should not be doing this on the app service provider, instead you should be doing this in the LoginController

Comment: But user if already in login state, how I can make him logout in LoginController ? In LoginController I only can check in login time. Is not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this better with Middlewares,

**Create a middleware CheckIfDeleted**

```
php artisan make:middleware CheckDeleted
```

**Open the CheckIfDeleted and update the handle method:**

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if(auth()->check() && auth()->user()->is_deleted === true){
        Auth::logout();
        $request->session()->invalidate();
        $request->session()->regenerateToken();
        return redirect('some error page?');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

**Open the Kernel.php (app/http folder), then add the new middleware in the web section (protected $middlewareGroups):**

```
\App\Http\Middleware\CheckIfDeleted::class,
```

I also recommend you implement the softDelete of laravel, you can use this guide from stack: [Laravel Soft Delete posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22426165/laravel-soft-delete-posts)

In this case if the user is deleted, they will get an error message, and you will still keep the record of the user :)